# Ruby Watir could not find firefox binary

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

Using ruby 1.9.3 and the latest version of watir-webdriver i get the following error when running a test script:

> C:/.../selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:120in 'path': Could not find Firefox binary (os-windows). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::Webdriver::Firefox::Binary.path=

I only just started getting this error after installing an older version of firefox in addition to a current version.  I am using watir-webdriver NOT selenium webdriver. Here are my requires

```
require 'highline/import'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'win32console'
require 'term/ansicolor'
require 'base64'
```

Error is with this line:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

I have uninstalled all versions of firefox and Ruby, and reinstalled only the latest.  The firefox installation directory is in my PATH. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Note that if you are using watir-webdriver you ARE using selenium-webdriver. Watir-webdriver is basically just a wrapper around selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 4):

Added this line after my 'requires' section and it works

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this also, take the path where mozilla exe is installed.

```
<WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
=> "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
```